Functions chaining with std::tuple
I'm trying to implement functions chain, that get bunch of different functions and member functions at compile time and execute them one by one and stop execution if processing function fails.
It may be any count of functions.
Now I'm stuck on the fact that std::tuple::get doesn't accept counted variable as template parameter.
How can I implement something like this?
#include <tuple>
#include <stdlib.h>

template<class...Fs>
class Functions
{
public:
    Functions(Fs...functions)
        : m_functions(functions...)
    {
    }

    template<class Arg>
    void operator()(Arg&& arg)
    {
        CallAll<sizeof...(Fs)>(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    }

private:
    std::tuple<Fs...> m_functions;

    template<size_t index, class Arg>
    decltype(auto) CallSingle(Arg&& arg)
    {
        return std::get<index>(m_functions)(arg);
    }


    template<size_t index, class Arg>
    void CallAll(Arg&& arg)
    {
        while (index != 0) {
            auto ret = CallSingle<index - 1>(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
            if (std::is_same<decltype(ret), bool>()) {
                if (!ret)
                    return;
            }
            index--; // error!
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Functions f{
        [](int x) { return x + 1; },
        [](int x) { return false; },
        [](int x) { return x + 3; }
    };

    f(42);
    return 0;
}

Compile error:
../../main.cpp: In member function 'void Functions<Fs>::CallAll(Arg&&)':
../../main.cpp:90:18: error: decrement of read-only location 'index'
   90 |             index--;
      |                  ^~
../../main.cpp:90:18: error: lvalue required as decrement operand


please do not remove includes from your code. When your code causes a compiler error include it in the question. Currently it requires quite some effort to understand what you are asking. You say you want this: --some code--. You already have the code written, so whats the issue?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai edited

NTTPs are compile time constants(constexpr). So you can't modify index like in index--

@user12002570 your demo only works because you didnt adjust CallSingle<index - 1>

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Ah, I missed to replace it. But yes, using count there won't work because it is not constexpr. So I am removing that comment.

index is not a variable, but a template parameter, so why you are expecting that index-- will work?

@MarekR i'm not expecting it'll work, i'm asking for advice, how can i implement this logic in allowed way

You can fix your code by replacing while loop with recursion.

either I miss something or this isnt "chaining", you just call one function after the other. Usually f( g(  h( x ))) is called chaining

@463035818_is_not_an_ai yes, i dont mean "chaining" as "call function with another function result recursively" but as "call bunch of function one after another and break execution if one of them will fail" as i said in my question

I undstand what you wrote, its just not chaining

The comment by @user12002570 points out the reason why your approach fails:

NTTPs are compile time constants(constexpr). So you can't modify index like in index--

However, you don't actually need to do it if you have C++17. Instead, you can make use of the fold expressions and get rid of your current auxiliary function callAll(). You also need to modify the signature of callOne(). Your operator() can be as follows.
    template <typename F, typename Arg>
    static bool callOne(F&& function, Arg&& arg){
        auto doCall=[&](){
            return std::forward<F>(function)(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
        };
        
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<decltype(doCall()), bool>){
            return doCall();
        }
        else{
            doCall();
            return true;
        }
    }

    template<class Arg>
    bool operator()(Arg&& arg)
    {
        return std::apply([&arg](auto&&... functions){
            return (callOne(std::forward<Fs>(functions),std::forward<Arg>(arg)) && ...);
        }, m_functions);
    }

which uses a lambda to capture the arg and std::apply to unpack the tuple for you. The fold expression then collects the results and automatically provides the short-circuiting behavior you are looking for.
Compared to the answer by @MarekR, this answer allows passing function pointers and other callables directly as arguments without first wrapping them in lambdas. This may be slightly simpler from the users' perspective.

It doesnt work with function returning void

@CaboomBom fixed.

Bast way to resolve this problem is using fold expression with && operator. Note that operator && is short circuiting, once first argument is evaluated to false the other argument is not evaluated.
template<class...Fs>
class Functions : public Fs...
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T&& x)
    {
        [[maybe_unused]]auto allSuccess = (continueResult(Fs::operator()(x)) && ...);
    }

    template<typename T>
    static constexpr bool continueResult(T&&) noexcept {
        return true;
    }

    static constexpr bool continueResult(bool r) noexcept {
        return r;
    }
};

https://godbolt.org/z/1x7arYqsY
This works since C++17 (fold expression were added to this standard), but before C++20 extra deduction guide is required. I used C++23 for nice logging features.
here is alternative version which can handle lambda returning void.

This solution doesn't work if there is a void function in bunch

You can tweak it to overcome this problem.

https://godbolt.org/z/ax7Pfss7n

Thank you! Your and Weijun Zhou solutions are what i wanted
